# Issues with the QListWidget clear function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to clear three QListWidgets so I can repopulate them with different data. I decided to do this:

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    m_openAction = new QAction("Open", this); // filemenu (Open)
        connect(m_openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));
        connect(m_openAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),m_listAlbum,SLOT(clear()));
        connect(m_openAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),m_listGenre,SLOT(clear()));
        connect(m_openAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),m_listArtist,SLOT(clear()));
}
```

The program compiles fine but crashes once I run it. Is there something wrong with the code here? Is there an easier method to delete the items in a QListWidget?

Comment: can you show definition or declaration of QAction please?

Comment: I didn't have any declaration, QAction is a class that comes with Qt

Comment: Use debugger to track down on which line the crash happens. If you have problems understanding the debugger's trace, then you can add it to your question and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: What is the value of m_listAlbum when the connect is called? Is it null? I don't think it is a good idea to clear the lists when openAction is triggered. User can still decide not to select any file.